# efficient and responsive way of text alignment bottom

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, response

I am trying to position"the answer is thee" text to the bottom of the page, It currently works.

The problem arises when i resize the screen the "big Text"  and "answer Text" falls out of alignment as the "Big text" element is full height (depending on the text amount). I would like the "answer text" to not be set height but to be responsive height depending on the size of the content area "big text"

link to fiddel [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/dbh7cbm0/3/)

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <link href="https://get.gridsetapp.com/35679/" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<li class="aside-open-close active">
  <a class="aside-opener" href="#">Q1. Question here.</a>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="columns">

      <div class="d1-d3">
        <p>one</p>
        <p>two</p>
        <p>three</p>
        <p class="answer-box">three - The answer is three</p>
      </div>

      <div class="d4-d6 grey-border">
        <p>big text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text
          herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig
          text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig
          text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig
          text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig
          text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig
          text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig
          text herebig text herebig text herebig text herebig text here</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.aside-opener {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
}

.answer-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  /* width: 100%; */
  height: 290px;
}

.grey-border {
  border: 1px solid rgba(68, 68, 68, .54);
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.grey-border p {
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 19px;
}
```

The image bellow is correct, but its got a set height, i need the height to be responsive or 100%

[image]

Comment: Np, ill get one up now

Comment: So each `li` should be 100% of the screen height?

Comment: Yeah, Ive posted a link to a fiddle. you will need to expand the screen width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need nested flexbox columns.

Nested child 'sections`inside your`li`needs to be a flex-container with`flex-direction:column`.

The `.columns` section is just given `display:flex` (each child is `flex:1`) so that the children are queal height.

Once we have achieved that we can push the final paragraph (answer text) to the bottom of its column with `margin-top:auto`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.slide {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.columns {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
.d1-d3 {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.aside-opener {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
  background: lightgrey;
}
.answer-box {
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: right;
}
.grey-border {
  border: 1px solid rgba(68, 68, 68, .54);
  flex: 1;
}
.grey-border p {
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 19px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="aside-open-close active">
    <a class="aside-opener" href="#">Q1. Question here.</a>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="columns">

        <div class="d1-d3">
          <p>one</p>
          <p>two</p>
          <p>three</p>
          <p class="answer-box">three - The answer is three</p>
        </div>

        <div class="d4-d6 grey-border">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur labore qui tenetur officia, hic illum fugit deleniti</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/dbh7cbm0/1/)